# OrientDB Removing one result set from another using the difference() function

Tags: orientdb

We are using version v.1.7-rc2 of OrientDB, embedded in our application, and I'm struggling to figure out a query for removing one set of results from another set of results.

For a simplified example, we have a class of type "A" which is organized in a directional hierarchy. The class has a "name" attribute defined as a string (referring to areas, regions, counties, cities, etc), and a "parent" edge defining a relationship from the child instances to the parent instances.

I was able to find the intersection of the result sets from the two sub-queries of my hierarchy using the instance() function:

```
select expand( $1 ) LET $2 = ( select from (traverse in('parent') from (select from A where name = 'Eastern')) where $depth > 0 and name like '%a%' ), $3 = ( select from (traverse in('parent') from (select from A where name = 'Eastern')) where $depth > 0 and name like '%o%' ), $1 = intersect( $2, $3 )
```

I thought I could accomplish the opposite effect if I used the difference() function:

```
select expand( $1 ) LET $2 = ( select from (traverse in('parent') from (select from A where name = 'Eastern')) where $depth > 0 and name like '%a%' ), $3 = ( select from (traverse in('parent') from (select from A where name = 'Eastern')) where $depth > 0 and name like '%o%' ), $1 = difference( $2, $3 )
```

but it returns zero records, when the sub queries for $2 and $3 run separately return record sets that overlap. What am I failing to understand? I've searched the forums and documentation, but haven't figured it out.

In the end, I want to take vertices found in one result set, and remove from it any vertices found in a second result set. I essentially want the analogous behavior of the SQL EXCEPT operator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#EXCEPT_operator).

Any ideas or directions would be extremely helpful!

Regards,

Andrew

Comment: I originally asked this question on the orientdb group: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/ciU62lcjQtU I'll repost any answers I get in both places. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: We fixed a bug on difference() months ago. Could you try with 2.0-SNAPSHOT?